# WatchOS6 handleActiveWorkoutRecovery not being called after workout crashes

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos-6

I'm creating a workout app and I'm trying to implement the workoutRecovery logic but the `handleActiveWorkoutRecovery` function is never being called when an app crashes or is forced closed.

Are there any special circumstances that must be met so that the handleActiveWorkoutRecovery?

```
func handleActiveWorkoutRecovery() {
        NSLog("log: handleActiveWorkoutRecovery");
        self.healthInfo.recoverWorkout()
        self.healthInfo.workoutRecovery = true
    }
```

Moreover, in `Content.swift` I have the following code so that in case the login is not working I could see visual feedback that the `handleActiveWorkoutRecovery` function is being called:

```
@EnvironmentObject var healthInfo: HealthInfo

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        if(healthInfo.workoutRecovery){
            Text("RECOVERY")
        }else{
            TestView()
        }
    }

}
```

When the app relaunches it never goes to The `Text("RECOVERY")` view.

Deployment target is 6.1 and I'm using an Apple Watch 4 running 6.1 beta 3

Ive also tested the native apple workout app and that seems to recover as it should

Comment: did you get to the bottom of this? I suspect it just doesn't work since watchOS 6?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: I have the same problem with watchOS 8. Any news ?